# Launch an application and wait until it has finished without blocking redraw

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have an interactive Win32 application and at some point I need to launch another application and wait until that other application has finished. During the time the other application runs, the interactive application shouldn't be responsive expect for resizing and moving the window (this implies of course that the interactive application still should continue redrawing).

My current approach is this:

1. Create a Thread T
2. Disable the main window (with `EnableWindow(handle, FALSE)`)
3. Continue message loop
4. Special `WM_APP` message sent from thread T will enable the main window again (`EnableWindow(handle, TRUE)`);

Thread T:

1. launch the application with `CreateProcess`
2. wait until application has terminated using `WaitForSingleObject`
3. post a special `WM_APP` message to the main window using `PostMessage`.
4. thread terminates here

This works fine, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Is there a better approach or should I continue like this?

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable.  Do you have any specific doubts?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit not really, I just wanted to hear some other opinions.

Comment: Well, that's what I would do straight off, without any further thought about it.  It would certainly work, and so why bother with more complex solutions?  :)

Comment: the best - use [MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684245(v=vs.85).aspx) - you absolute not need create additional threads

Comment: I mean, you could go messing about with the input to the message loop, MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(), say.  That would mean modifying code that already works fine, so it's not something I would bother with just to avoid another thread.  If it's already simple, reasonably efficient and works well, why tinker:)

Comment: @RbMm LOL...... we may have to agree to differ:)

Comment: Of course, the main objection to MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() is the typing required to enter it:)

Comment: "If it's already simple, reasonably efficient and works well, why tinker:) " - for make the best solution. for high quality professional code. create additional, absolute non needed thread here - no professional, not effective and not the best way

Comment: @RbMm 'Best' solution?  You consider modifying the input to the message handling/dispatch loop, (something that is already working), a professional approach?   Posting messages, and having them handled in the 'usual' manner, is not something to be worried about in 'high quality professional code'.  'absolute non needed thread' - yes.  Expedient and flexible, also yes.    As I said, we may have to agree to differ:)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit - yes, we can agree to be differ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, just make sure to use `PostMessage()` for

> send a special WM_APP message to the main window

to avoid deadlock if the main thread happens to wait for thread T.

As commenter noted, an **alternative for creating a thread** is to use a message loop with [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684245(v=vs.85).aspx).

The advantages I see:

- There is no additional thread required, so there will be no worries about thread-related problems such as race conditions and deadlocks. These problems are often hard to find and debug (typically they only happen on customer machines), so I try to avoid threads as much as possible.
- The program flow for creating the process and waiting for it is simpler. It can be sequential instead of event-based like the thread solution.

You have to judge for yourself if this is a *better* approach for your scenario.

A function that can be used to **wait for a process** (or any other waitable handle) **while processing messages** could be as follows. It's implementation is pretty involved (for background info see the links at the end of my answer) but usage is quite easy (see example afterwards).

```
// Function to process messages until the state of any of the given objects is signaled, 
// the timeout is reached or a WM_QUIT message is received.
// Parameter hDialog can be nullptr, if there is no dialog.
//
// Returns ERROR_SUCCESS if any of the given handles is signaled.
// Returns ERROR_TIMEOUT in case of timeout.
// Returns ERROR_CANCELLED if the WM_QUIT message has been received.
// Returns the value of GetLastError() if MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() fails.

DWORD WaitForObjectsWithMsgLoop( 
    HWND hDialog, const std::vector<HANDLE>& handles, DWORD timeOutMillis = INFINITE )
{
    if( handles.empty() )
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    DWORD handleCount = static_cast<DWORD>( handles.size() );
    DWORD startTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD duration = 0;
    do
    {
        DWORD status = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(
            handleCount, handles.data(), 
            timeOutMillis - duration, 
            QS_ALLINPUT, 
            MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE );

        if( status == WAIT_FAILED )
        {
            // MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() has failed.
            return GetLastError();
        }
        else if( status >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && status < WAIT_OBJECT_0 + handleCount )
        {
            // Any of the handles is signaled.
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }
        else if( status == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + handleCount )
        {
            // New input is available, process it.
            MSG msg;
            while( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
            {
                if( msg.message == WM_QUIT )
                {
                    // End the message loop because of quit message.
                    PostQuitMessage( static_cast<int>( msg.wParam ) );
                    return ERROR_CANCELLED;
                }
                // Enable message filter hooks (that's what the system does in it's message loops).
                // You may use a custom code >= MSGF_USER.
                // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050428-00/?p=35753
                if( ! CallMsgFilter( &msg, MSGF_USER ) )
                {
                    // Optionally process dialog messages.
                    if( ! hDialog || ! IsDialogMessage( hDialog, &msg ) )
                    {
                        // Standard message processing.
                        TranslateMessage( &msg );
                        DispatchMessage( &msg );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        duration = GetTickCount() - startTime;
    }
    while( duration < timeOutMillis );

    // Timeout reached.
    return ERROR_TIMEOUT;
}
```

The function could be used in a dialog box procedure as follows. Error handling omitted for brevity.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK YourDialogProc( HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    static bool s_childProcessRunning = false;

    switch( message )
    {
        case YourMessageToLaunchProcess:
        {
            // prevent reentrancy in case the process is already running
            if( s_childProcessRunning )
            {
                MessageBoxW( hDlg, L"Process already running", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR );
                return TRUE;
            }
            // Prepare CreateProcess() arguments
            STARTUPINFO si{ sizeof(si) };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi{};
            wchar_t command[] = L"notepad.exe"; // string must be writable!

            // Launch the process
            if( CreateProcessW( NULL, command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi ) )
            {
                // Set flag to prevent reentrancy. 
                s_childProcessRunning = true;  

                // Wait until the child process exits while processing messages
                // to keep the window responsive.  
                DWORD waitRes = WaitForObjectsWithMsgLoop( hDlg, { pi.hProcess } );
                // TODO: Check waitRes for error

                s_childProcessRunning = false;

                // Cleanup
                CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
                CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
            }
            return TRUE;
        }

        // more message handlers...
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Obligatory Old New Thing links:

- [Pumping messages while waiting for a period of time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060126-00/?p=32513)
- [The dialog manager, part 4: The dialog loop](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050401-00/?p=35993/)
- [Rescuing thread messages from modal loops via message filters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050428-00/?p=35753)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very good answer. I was already using `PostMessage`, the wording in the question was not optimal.

Comment: Well, 'so there will be no worries about thread-related problems such as race conditions and deadlocks' what?  How could there be any such thing?  It's just sequential code - create process, wait for it to finish, postMessage.  'The program flow for creating the process and waiting for it is simpler. It can be sequential instead of event-based like the thread solution.' - this is completely and totally upside-down and incorrect.

Comment: 'so I try to avoid threads as much as possible' - I noticed - you are spreading unnecessary FUD about 'race conditions and deadlocks' where there is zero chance of that happening in this application.

Comment: You are, essentially, calling DoEvents() in an event-handler loop and using a flag to prevent reentrancy.  That is ummm.... 'not optimal' :(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I don't think that there is such a thing like a trivial thread. The correct patterns might be obvious for you and me but certainly not for the less experienced developers. Dead-lock issue is very real even in such "simple" cases (`PostMessage()` vs. `SendMessage()`) and code evolves and won't stay simple for all time.